# Is taking disposable utensils considered stealing?

Tags: gezel-stealing

My friends and I are debating whether or not stockpiling disposable utensils from our university dining hall would be considered גזלה (eg taking 10 spoons at once to use for cereal in your own room).

Can anyone think of any מקורות that would shed light on this either way?

Comment: When you do it, do you hide the spoons away so nobody sees you taking them out of the dining hall?

Comment: Not necessarily. But it's not as if someone is standing and guarding the utensils, so conceivably when the utensils are taken, no one would now.

Comment: It sounds like it is. The intention of the utensil supply is for the purpose of eating your current meal, not for saving for future meals. Unless, the owner doesn't mind or expects people to take extras (and, perhaps, the cafeteria owner DOES expect this - in which case, taking a reasonable supply of extras may be OK.) That's a tough call, as you don't really know for certain. Safest idea is to ask someone in charge if you can take a few extras. If you want to act as a *Chasid* go above the plain rule and only take what you need, even if they DO allow taking extras.

Comment: Welcome to the site! To learn more about it consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @ekom12 Is the "use for cereal in your own room" one of the uses intended by the cafeteria?

Comment: I guess you must have edited in the "cereal use", later? My guess - if you bought the cereal from the café, yesterday, and didn't take spoons, then, and, today you buy more cereal, then taking extras doesn't sound like stealing, as you were "entitled" to yesterday's spoon, anyway. Then, again, this is not "stockpiling". But, I don't think you can "reverse" and take 2 spoons, today with 1 cereal in anticipation of buying another tomorrow & not taking a spoon, tomorrow.

Comment: @Avrohom Yitzchok unclear. We have never asked the staff explicitly. But many students do in fact take plastic ware in this manner.

Comment: If they were about to toss the utensils away, and if you asked if you could have them (as oppose to stealing them) that would be most preferable (and Kosher)!

Answer (score 1):

It presumably depends on  the policy of the institution. E.g. my yeshiva expressly prohibited it. If you ask the person in charge and they say it is ok, then you have permission

Answer (score 0):

The [Shulchan Aruch (C.M. 359)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.359?lang=bi) writes:

> אסור לגזול או לעשוק אפילו כל שהוא בין מישראל בין מעכו"ם.
> ואם הוא דבר דליכא מאן דקפיד ביה שרי, כגון ליטול מהחבילה או מהגדר לחצוץ
> בו שיניו. ואף זה אוסר בירושלמי ממדת חסידות:
>
> It’s forbidden to steal or exploit (even) any amount, whether from a
> Jew or a non-Jew; And if it is an object that is not concerning, it is
> permitted; such as to take [a straw] from a package or [taking a splinter]
> from the fence to brush his teeth with; and even this is prohibited by
> the Jeruselamite (Talmud), as a quality of fervency.

The [Sema](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.359.1?lang=bi&with=Me%27irat%20Einayim&lang2=en) explains the reason to not allow taking even a negligible amount:

> ואף זה אוסר בירושלמי הטעם כתב הנ"י דאלו עושה כן כל אחד נמצא החבילה כלה והגדר נהרס עכ"ל:
>
> The reason is, writes the Nemukei Yosef, if everyone would do this, the package would be exhausted and the fence would be ruined.

So, in this case, if the university would never be bothered by the amount of disposable utensils being taken, it is strictly speaking permissible, but recommended not to take any (more than the expected one for that meal, of course). A larger amount (10 at once) that is not necessarily overlooked is forbidden. This is true even if in the particular case the university doesn't care, so long as it is an amount that they might reasonably be strict about (three maybe?); until receiving clear permission. (BTW, the person behind the counter might not be the one who can give permission.)

Answer (score -1):

There's a simple principle of proving it (Mishnah BM 6,2) "כל המשנה ידו על התחתונה", meaning "Whoever changes the established conditions has the lower hand".

As in this case you unanimously behave **against the established conditions**, the burden of proof (*of your innocence*) is on you, until then **it's Safek Gezel**.

EDIT: *"the established condition" is considered either by "אזלינן בתר רובא" - "the majority of use/rs" principle, or "אנן סהדי" - "we/everybody would testify" by a Bet Din.*

Comment: What do you mean by "established conditions" and how do you know what they are here?